# Failed to compile, after adding 'moment' package in Angular 13.3.1 app

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13

Angular 13.3.1 app was running well on Windows 10 development environment - Node 14.19.0, npm 6.14.16.

But after installing `moment` package, failed to compile.

I can see many TS2314, TS2307 errors in node_modules when trying to run the app by executing `npm run dev`

For example

```
TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/dialog' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

```
TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires 6 type argument(s)
```

I have tried to remove package-lock.json and node_modules, and ran 'npm install' again. but no hope

Comment: Did you try removing node_modules and running `npm install`?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I tried removing both package-lock.json and node modules, and running `npm install`, but same errors